# Demonstration of permutation with repetition

Tags: combinatorics

Let $m$, $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_n$ positive integers such that $m$ = $a_1$+$\cdots$+$a_n$.

Prove that

$$\frac{m!}{a_1!a_2!\cdots a_n}\in\ N$$

Comment: There is a lemma which says that the product of $n$ consecutive numbers is divided by $n!$. Your problem would follow immediately from the lemma. Unfortunately I'm not sure which one is harder :)

Answer (score 0):

$$m!=\prod_{i=1}^{i=a_1}a_i\prod_{i=a_1+1}^{i=a_1+a_2}a_i...\prod_{i=a_1+a_2+...a_{n-1}+1}^{i=a_1+a_2+...+a_n}a_i$$

Now $\frac{m!}{a_1!a_2!\cdots a_n}$ becomes $$\binom{a_1}{a_1}\binom{a_1+a_2}{a_2}\binom{a_1+a_2+a_3}{a_3}...\binom{m}{a_n}$$ which is evidently an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a coefficient before the term $x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}...x_n^{a_n}$ after full expansion of $(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)^m.$